# mongodb elastic search autoindexing

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Iam facing issues from elastic search auto indexing with mongodb. When i update and delete the record from the mongodb it doesn't get indexing in elastic search so how to auto index the mongodb recrords in elastic search while update and delete the records.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That means show a configuration where this does not work. Note the "Minimal and Complete" which means please don't dump your very large configuration here. Create a "minimal" configuration on a single collection with a few entries in a way that is does not auto-index. Then people can show you what is wrong, if you don't work it out yourself during that process.